# Docker Compose with Traefik and Mosquitto - Secure Websocket Issue

Tags: vue.js, websocket, mqtt

I have been spinning my wheels for a full day now trying to figure this out.  I'm still relatively new to Traefik.  The goal is to get a secure MQTT broker up in the cloud.  The problem is I can connect using any MQTT client using `mqtts://broker.mydomain.com:8883`, but when I need to use websockets via `wss://broker.mydomain.com:9001`, I am having no luck.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.6"

networks:
  traefik-global-proxy:
    name: "traefik-global-proxy"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    container_name: "traefik"
    networks:
      - traefik-global-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8883:8883"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      # - "./traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml"
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./logs:/logs"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--accesslog=true"
      - "--accesslog.filepath=/logs/access.log"

      # Entrypoints
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.mqtt.address=:8883"
      - "--entrypoints.websocket.address=:9001"

      # Redirect http to https
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https" # Let's encrypt configuration
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=email@domain.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.broker.mydomain.com`)
        && (PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=auth"
      # echo $(htpasswd -nb user password) | sed -e s/\\$/\\$\\$/g
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=username:REDACTED"

  mqtt:
    image: "eclipse-mosquitto"
    container_name: "mosquitto"
    networks:
      - traefik-global-proxy
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "8883"
      - "9001"
    volumes:
      - "./mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config/"
      - "./logs:/logs"
      - "./data:/data"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"

      - "traefik.http.routers.mqtt.rule=Host(`broker.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mqtt.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mqtt.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.mqtt.loadbalancer.server.port=9001"

      - "traefik.tcp.routers.mqtt.rule=HostSNI(`broker.mydomain.com`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.mqtt.entrypoints=mqtt"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.mqtt.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.tcp.services.mqtt.loadbalancer.server.port=8883"
```

**mosquitto.conf**

```
listener 8883 0.0.0.0
protocol mqtt

listener 9001 0.0.0.0
protocol websockets

allow_anonymous true
password_file /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.password

persistence true
persistence_file /data/mosquitto.db

log_dest file /logs/mosquitto.log
```

Here is a standalone Vue test created with `vue create mqtt-vue` that is not successful:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
import mqtt from "mqtt";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  data: () => ({
    connection: {
      host: "broker.mydomain.com",
      port: 9001,
      protocol: "wss",
      username: "USERNAME",
      password: "PASSWORD",
      endpoint: "/",

      clean: true, // Set to false to receive QoS 1 and 2 messages while offline
      connectTimeout: 3 * 1000,
      reconnectPeriod: 1 * 1000,
      // clientId: `my-client-${uuidv4().substring(0, 8)}`,
      keepalive: 30,
    },
    client: {
      connected: false,
    },
  }),
  mounted() {
    console.log("MOUNTED");
    const { host, port, endpoint, ...options } = this.connection;

    const connectUrl = `wss://${host}:${port}${endpoint}`;
    console.log(connectUrl, options);
    this.client = mqtt.connect(connectUrl, options);
    this.client.on("connect", this._onConnect);
    this.client.on("error", (error) => {
      console.warn("Connection failed", error);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    _onConnect() {
      console.log("onConnect", this.client.connected);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I must be doing something stupid.  It's just not clicking for me.  Hopefully someone can point out the issue and I, among others, can learn from this post in the future.

Comment: Just something to try, remove the `endpoint` or set it to `/mqtt` as that is the expected path for MQTT over WebSockets

Comment: I believe that `traefik.http.routers.mqtt.entrypoints=websecure` means traefik will be using port 443 for the websocket connection but you are attempting to connect on port 9001; change the port or use `traefik.http.routers.mqtt.entrypoints=websocket`.

Comment: You are my hero!  I can't believe I didn't see that.  Hopefully the above full example along with your suggested solve helps people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments `traefik.http.routers.mqtt.entrypoints=websecure` means traefik will be using port 443 for the websocket connection (due to `entrypoints.websecure.address=:443`).

You are attempting to connect on port 9001; change the port or use `traefik.http.routers.mqtt.entrypoints=websocket`.

Unfortunately traefik config files can be quite hard to read/debug!